# Linker - Copying data from FLASH memory to RAM

Tags: c, gcc, linker, microcontroller, linker-scripts

I have some question regarding to linker script.
What data needs to be copied from FLASH to RAM in MCU by the startup code (is it only .data segment?)? Why do we need that?

As I can see, every linker script is declaring FLASH memory with attribute (rx). Do I need to change it to (rwx) manually in order to have possibility of using FLASH in a runtime for example in order to store any statistics data?

Comment: It depends on your MCU architecture. If you use `rwx` for the .text segment, you will face a runtime error. Because it's a hardware-relevant issue and software is unable to write directly to it (AFAIK, unlike the read operation, NOR FLASH memories need a special process to write). The good news is that all the MCU's has a particular peripheral to writing into FLASH at runtime and, we can use it as non-volatile memory. Just take a look at your MCU reference manual or its SDK.

Comment: About your first question, startup code will read a region of code that contains the initial values of your variables and will set their values.

Comment: .data generally means non-zero, initialized, read/write data.  so it has to be in ram before the C code starts.   But ram is volatile, so it needs to be copied from non volatile to ram before you start the code derived from C.   read only data can be marked differently and remain in flash.  I would avoid all the rx, rwx, etc, remove those completely and control the segments by name.  YMMV

Comment: So in summary, the Flash memory is marked as read only because we are not able to write into it in on cycle, as it is in RAM memory (we cannot write to it in code in the same way, but we need to use extra peripheral, which will do whole procedure of write). Am I right with it?

Answer (score 1):

Primarily, there are 6 sections in the **Memory Layout** of microcontrollers.

1. **`.isr_vector`** **PLACED IN: FLASH**
   Code's entry point is the reset vector which basically is a pointer to the first instruction that is to be executed after reset. This is the startup code section containing all the 'Interrupt Service Routine vectors' which are pointers to interrupt handler functions.
2. **`.text`** **PLACED IN: FLASH**
   This section is also called as code section and is placed just after the `.isr_vector` section. It written with the executable instructions.
3. **`.data`** **PLACED IN: FLASH; COPIED TO RAM**
   Initialized data such as global variables and static variables are stored in this segment.
4. **`.bss`** **PLACED IN: RAM**
   'This section is for uninitialized data and the date will be assigned to zero in the startup code.
5. `heap`  **PLACED IN: RAM**
   Used for dynamic memory allocation during runtime.
6. `stack` **PLACED IN: RAM**
   Stack stores temporary variables declared, defined and stored inside a function during runtime.

> - What data needs to be copied from FLASH to RAM in MCU by the startup code (is it only .data segment?)?

To answer your first question, `.data` section needs to be copied from Flash memory to RAM memory.

> - Why do we need that?

When microcontroller is powered on or reset, the program code is stored in non-volatile memory i.e., flash memory. While RAM being faster to access than flash, RAM memory is erased when the microcontroller is turned off or reset.

- RAM is faster and flexible than flash memory, hence it is preferred for storing data that is frequently required and needs to be modified.
- Flash memory on the other hand is not byte-addressable, which means that if we want to erase a particular byte, we need to erase a complete sector or page, which is not ideal when we wish to access only few bytes for modifications.
- Therefore, during initial setup of the program code, every initialized static and global variable is stored in the flash memory, and later copied into RAM for **easy accessibility and modifiability**
- In summary, copying the .data section from flash to RAM is necessary to optimize program performance and reduce power consumption in embedded systems by allowing the program to quickly access and modify initialized data during runtime.
- This also means that **`.data` section occupies memory in RAM as well as in FLASH!**

> every linker script is declaring FLASH memory with attribute (rx). Do I need to change it to (rwx) manually in order to have possibility of using FLASH in a runtime

Yes, it is recommended to include `w`. If you are going to write to flash memory during runtime without `w` write access, it may lead to unknown behavior. It is better to include (rwx) in the linker script, when you want to access the flash during runtime. *On a side note and rather important!*, It is not recommended to make changes in the flash during runtime as the code residing in the same flash memory may get affected and lead to errors or faults.

***How I tackled this problem:***
I wanted to do the same (To write to the flash memory during runtime), so I created a memory section `.data_storage` in my flash memory and gave `(rw)` access to it. Now the code is safe in the `(rx)` region of my flash, while the `.data_storage` can be accessed during runtime with `(rw)`.

***To add more to this:***
Because `.data` section is stored in RAM as well as in flash, it has 2 memory locations. First where it is loaded that is flash memory address also known as **'Load Memory Address'(LMA)** and later copied into RAM memory address called **'Virtual Memory Address'(VMA)** or **Run Address**.

**Example to verify where `.data` is stored.**:
This is the memory layout of a STM32F103C8T6 board, generated using [arm-none-eabi-readelf](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/binutils-arm-none-eabi/index.html) command used on the .elf file of the project. *`.data_storage` is a section in flash memory which I created for my purpose which can be ignored.*

Everything that is stored in and from 0x08000000 comes under Flash 'ROM' type Memory. 0x02000000 and beyond is for RAM Memory. Total size of my Flash memory is 64KB and Ram size is 20KB.

[image: Image of Section Headers in Memory Layout]

To get total flash memory used, we can add the sizes of
`.isr_vector`+`.text`+`.rodata`+`.init_array`+`fini_array`+`.data` = 0x10C + 0xA7DC + 0x1B8 + 0x4 + 0x4 + 0x1E8 = 0xAC90(base16) = 44176(base10)

Hence, total size of flash which is used should be 44176 Bytes.

and for RAM size used,
`.data`+`.bss`+`._user_heap_stack` = 0x1E8 + 0x172c + 0x904 = 0x2218(Base16) = 8728(Base10)

Total size of RAM which is used is 8728 Bytes.

Above calculations match with the STM32CubeIDE's memory-size-used indication:

[image: Flah and Ram memory usage indication]

**Which proves that `.data` is indeed stored in RAM and FLASH.**